# Understand scipy's shapiro behavior when inserting two columns dataframe instead of one

Tags: python, scipy, normal-distribution, unspecified-behavior

I have dataframe similar to this:

```
codes=[1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3]
values=[702,713,701,721,705,715,703,712,706,710,702,715,698,718,704]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(codes, values)),
               columns =['code', 'val'])

>>>

   code val
0   1   702
1   3   713
2   1   701
3   3   721
4   1   705
5   3   715
6   1   703
7   3   712
8   1   706
9   3   710
10  1   702
11  3   715
12  1   698
13  3   718
14  1   704
```

I want to check if there is significant difference betweeen the values of group 1 and group 3. For that I have used scipy's shapiro test to check if data is normally distributed.

I did something I believe is mistake in my original code:

```
shapiro1=stats.shapiro(df[df['code'] == 1]
>>>
ShapiroResult(statistic=0.6468859314918518, pvalue=4.644487489713356e-05)

shapiro3=stats.shapiro(df[df['code'] == 3]
>>>
ShapiroResult(statistic=0.6508359909057617, pvalue=0.00011963312863372266)
```

as you can see I kind of filter the dataframe by the code and not by the values, so I insert the dataframe with one code value and two columns.

Then i did something I believe is fix:

```
stats.shapiro(df[df['code'] == 3]['val'])
>>>
ShapiroResult(statistic=0.967737078666687, pvalue=0.8816877007484436)
```

so then it is not normal distributed.

When I print the  part I inserted to the shapiro:

```
df[df['code'] == 3]
```

I have dataframe with two columns, what does it check? the "codes" distribution? some mix of them?

My question here:
**what does it check when I insert to two columns df to the  shapiro test?**

Edit: I have been able to add  more columns and to run shapiro test on them (just with random numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source on github](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/08390dcde02d048a4a1b07a132510a9d0ea6f28c/scipy/stats/morestats.py#L1663), the first thing that happens on calling `stats.shapiro()` is that the input is passed to [`numpy.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html).  This returns a view (if possible) or copy of your data as a flattened, contiguous, 1-D array.

Basically, it puts all the columns into one big, long bucket and proceeds to calculate the Shapiro-Wilk test.